# How to select all field from table with distinct (field x) ?? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try this code

```
function catstore($id)
    {   
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('store_id');
        $this->db->from('products');
        //$this->db->join('products','products.store_id = products.store_id');
        $this->db->where('cat_id', $id);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();       
    }
```

it produces only the distinct store_id but i want all column of the table with distinct rows based on store_id

Suggest me any option

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can try using group_by

```
function catstore($id)
{   
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    //$this->db->join('products','products.store_id = products.store_id');
    $this->db->where('cat_id', $id);
    $this->db->group_by('store_id');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result->result();       
}
```

I know this question is already long time ago, but one may be looking for the same problem like me, and this is how I solved it.

Comment: I found this more useful than using `$this->db->distinct();`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can omit the `select` function altogether. If you are selecting all (*) from a table you do not need to use this function. When omitted, CodeIgniter assumes you wish to `SELECT *`

See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

Or..

You can pass comma separated values to `select` function. So pass all column names separated by comma that you want to select

```
function catstore($id)
    {   
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('store_id, column1, column2, cloumn3');
        $this->db->from('products');
        //$this->db->join('products','products.store_id = products.store_id');
        $this->db->where('cat_id', $id);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();       
    }
```